# Runtime error when archiving NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

**SOLVED and UPDATED CODE.**

I have implemented a image cache that caches images to disk. It works so that the UIImage is archived to `NSData` and written to disk with `[data writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error]` where path is the imageURL (striped from '/' so it wont be mistaken for directories). Along with this there is a dictionary were keys is `imageURL` and value is a timestamp so i can remove the oldest images if dictionary gets full. This is the basic functionality of it all.

The problem:
Everything works good for a while then (seemingly random occasions) i get this error:

```
-[__NSCFType encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16eaf810
```

on this line (NSData *registerData = ...) in method below:

```
- (void)persistData:(UIImage *)image forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    @synchronized(self) { // looks like this have no effect
        NSData *imageData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:image];
        [NSFileManager THSNstoreData:imageData forKey:key];
        NSData *registerData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_imageCacheRegister]; // debugger stops here
        [NSFileManager THSNstoreData:registerData forKey:_dictionaryKey];
    }
}
```

I have checked the dictionary by hand and the address to the dictionary or any of its keys/values are not the same as the address of the instance in the error message.

I'm really confused here... according to some stuff i have read the `__NSCFType` is used when memory is recycled. So that would imply that something gets released to early... or something completely different.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I am using ARC of course. And also a dependency injection framework that enables me to use this as a singleton.

Here are all the code in the class:

```
#import "ImageDiskCache.h"
#import "NSMutableDictionary+Techsson.h"

@interface ImageDiskCache () {
    NSString            *_dictionaryKey;
    NSMutableDictionary *_imageCacheRegister;
    dispatch_queue_t    _diskQue;
    NSInteger           _maxCachedImagesCount;
    NSInteger           _numberOfImagesToRemove;
}

@end

@implementation ImageDiskCache

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _maxCachedImagesCount = 50;
        _numberOfImagesToRemove = 5;
        _dictionaryKey = @"cacheRegistry";
        _diskQue = dispatch_queue_create("diskQue", NULL);
        dispatch_async(_diskQue, ^{
            NSData *data = [NSFileManager THSNdataForKey:_dictionaryKey];
            if ( data )
            {
                _imageCacheRegister = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
            }
            else
            {
                _imageCacheRegister = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:_maxCachedImagesCount];
            }
        });
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)readImageForKey:(NSString *)key withCompletionHandler:(UIImageCompletionHandler)completion
{
    if ( _imageCacheRegister && key )
    {
        dispatch_async(_diskQue, ^{
            NSString *stripedKey = [self stripedKeyForKey:key];
            if ( [_imageCacheRegister safeObjectForKey:stripedKey] )
            {
                NSData *imageData = [NSFileManager THSNdataForKey:stripedKey];
                UIImage *image = imageData ? [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:imageData] : nil;
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    completion(image);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                completion(nil);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        completion(nil);
    }
}

- (void)wrightImage:(UIImage *)image forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if ( !image || !key || [key isEqualToString:@""] || !_imageCacheRegister )
    {
        return;
    }

    dispatch_async(_diskQue, ^{
        NSString *stripedKey = [self stripedKeyForKey:key];
        if ( [_imageCacheRegister safeCount] < _maxCachedImagesCount )
        {
            [_imageCacheRegister safeSetObject:[self timeStampAsData] forKey:stripedKey];
            [self persistData:image forKey:stripedKey];
        }
        else
        {
            NSArray *keys = [_imageCacheRegister safeKeysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
                NSTimeInterval timeStampObj1 = [self timeStampFromData:obj1];
                NSTimeInterval timeStampObj2 = [self timeStampFromData:obj2];
                if ( timeStampObj1 > timeStampObj2 )
                {
                    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
                }
                else if ( timeStampObj1 < timeStampObj2 )
                {
                    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
                }
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
            }];

            NSArray *toRemove = [keys subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange([keys count] - _numberOfImagesToRemove, _numberOfImagesToRemove)];
            [_imageCacheRegister safeRemoveObjectsForKeys:toRemove];
            for ( NSString *k in toRemove )
            {
                [NSFileManager THSNdeleteDataForKey:k];
            }
            [_imageCacheRegister safeSetObject:[self timeStampAsData] forKey:stripedKey];
            [self persistData:image forKey:stripedKey];
        }
    });
}

#pragma - private methods

- (NSString *)stripedKeyForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSString *stripedKey = [key stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];

    return stripedKey;
}

- (NSData *)timeStampAsData
{
    NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSData *timeStampData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&timeStamp length:sizeof(NSTimeInterval)];

    return timeStampData;
}

- (NSTimeInterval)timeStampFromData:(NSData *)timeStampData
{
    NSTimeInterval timeStamp;
    [timeStampData getBytes:&timeStamp length:sizeof(NSTimeInterval)];

    return timeStamp;
}

- (void)persistData:(UIImage *)image forKey:(NSString *)key
{
//    @synchronized(self) {
        NSData *imageData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:image];
        [NSFileManager THSNstoreData:imageData forKey:key];
        NSData *registerData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_imageCacheRegister];
        [NSFileManager THSNstoreData:registerData forKey:_dictionaryKey];
//    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because you're using mutable data? NSKeyedArchiver has different methods for that

```
- (id)initForWritingWithMutableData:(NSMutableData *)data
```

Try this method

```
- (void)persistData:(UIImage *)image forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        NSData *imageData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:image];
        [NSFileManager THSNstoreData:imageData forKey:key];

        NSMutableData *registerData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:registerData];
        [archiver encodeObject:_imageCacheRegister forKey:@"root"];
        [archiver finishEncoding];

        [NSFileManager THSNstoreData:registerData forKey:_dictionaryKey];
    }
}
```

Hope that helps mate

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try this tomorrow and report back on the result.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but this had no effect on the issue. I have put more of the code in the _diskOne que and now the issue seems solved. I'm not sure, but for now i don't get any crashes.. yet.

Comment: Perhaps because you are executing on a different thread, the pointer gets released from time to time while the object itself is still retained? Seems the issue might be depending on the amount of lower priority processes stacked in the queue causing too long a delay? Just some thoughts but glad you've resolved the issue